# Add start and end attribute to node and edge in gexf file

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have a `.gexf` file that contains nodes and edges with IDs and labels. I generated this `.gexf`file from a `.gml` file using `networkx`. Here's the code for that:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.read_gml('data/gml/test.gml') # read in gml file as Graph
nx.write_gexf(G, "output/test.gexf") # write to gexf format
```

The next thing I want to do, is to add a `start`and `end` attribute to every node and every edge in my file.

**So basically, I want this**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<gexf version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <graph defaultedgetype="undirected" mode="static">
    <nodes>
      <node id="clock" label="clock" />
      <node id="beach" label="beach" />
      <node id="sun" label="sun" />
      <node id="sea" label="sea" />
      <node id="sand" label="sand" />
      <node id="guitar" label="guitar" />
      (...)
    </nodes>
    <edges>
      <edge id="0" source="ice" target="shoe" weight="0.9995600294856769" />
      <edge id="1" source="ice" target="toothbrush" weight="0.9992457544219484" />
      <edge id="1533" source="snake" target="ant" weight="0.9999144063155566" />
      (...)
      <edge id="1534" source="mosquito" target="jellyfish" weight="0.9994175606336606" />
      <edge id="1535" source="ant" target="star" weight="0.9994226236705537" />
    </edges>
  </graph>
</gexf>
```

**to look like this** (note the `dynamic`mode and `start` and `end` attributes):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<gexf version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.1draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <graph defaultedgetype="undirected" mode="dynamic">
    <nodes>
      <node id="clock" label="clock" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <node id="beach" label="beach" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <node id="sun" label="sun" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <node id="sea" label="sea" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <node id="sand" label="sand" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <node id="guitar" label="guitar" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      (...)
    </nodes>
    <edges>
      <edge id="0" source="ice" target="shoe" weight="0.9995600294856769" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <edge id="1" source="ice" target="toothbrush" weight="0.9992457544219484" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <edge id="1533" source="snake" target="ant" weight="0.9999144063155566" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      (...)
      <edge id="1534" source="mosquito" target="jellyfish" weight="0.9994175606336606" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
      <edge id="1535" source="ant" target="star" weight="0.9994226236705537" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
    </edges>
  </graph>
</gexf>
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find any documentation (neither for `networkx` nor for `pygexf`) on how to write a dyamic `gexf` file and add a `start`and `end` attribute to every (already existing) node and edge. Can anyone please help me with this?

**UPDATE**: 
When I use

```
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'start', '2000-02-20')
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'end', '2000-02-22')
```

To set the edge attributes, I get the correct output, e.g.:

```
<edge id="0" source="great" target="wait" weight="0.998675772419067" start="2000-02-20" end="2000-02-22" />
```

However, when I do:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'start','2000-02-20')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'end','2000-02-22')
```

I get:

```
<node id="blue" label="blue">
    <attvalues>
      <attvalue for="0" value="2000-02-20" />
      <attvalue for="1" value="2000-02-22" />
    </attvalues>
```

How can I set the `start` and `end`attribute *within* the `node` tag?

Comment: When I had to do the same thing I did it with BeautifulSoup modifying the gexf directly without using networkx. Any xml library will help you but networkx doesn't have a direct support for dynamic graphs

Comment: I could really use a solution to this as I need to marry a networkx graph (start, end metadata if possible) to the GEXF format. I'll post my solution here once I am done. It will likely involve modifying the XML structure after GEXF generation.

Answer (score 0):

Came across that same problem. Networkx 2.1 still does not support that, but there is a workaround:

1. Write the .gexf file as usual
2. [Download Gephi 0.9.2](https://gephi.org/users/download/) and open the .gexf file
3. Go to Data Laboratory and press 'Merge Columns'. Now select the start and end column and 'Merge Strategy': 'Create time interval'. Now your Interval column is filled with <[`start`, `end`]>
4. Go to File > Export > Graph file... and select File Format:GEXF Files. Your nodes now contain the `start` and `end` attribute.